# How to create horizontal rectangle that fills up or decreases color area depending on input value

Tags: xcode, graph, uiview, rectangles

I know there's a name for this, but I can't seem to think of it (or even provide a better title description.)

Image an empty horizontal rectangle - left edge has a value of 0, right edge has a value of 5.  Now above it, there's a graph with an x-axis range of 0-5.  When the plotting of the graph begins, the x-axis value is used as input to the horizontal rectangle in order to show, using a specific color, the area of the value.

Example: when input is given to the rectangle, the graph's x-axis value is 2.5.  The rectangle now has half of it's area covered in red starting from the left edge.  The value now is 3.  Same idea, the area now stretches to "3".

It's a dynamic horizontal graph of sorts.  Anywho, how do I go about creating this for iOS? Is there a class that's already built?  Or do I just use rectangle drawing methods in a UIView subclass?

Thanks

update: here's an image of what I'm after: [Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5oJ8.png)

Comment: Maybe you need to use a UISlider https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider

Comment: I kept reading more into (https://useyourloaf.com/blog/ib-designable-custom-views-in-interface-builder/) and like the look of it better than a UISlider, but thanks anyway MrGreen